# Retrieve data from a bookmark

Tags: c#-4.0, ms-word

Could you please let me know how can i retrieve data from a ms-word document bookmark dynamically, using c#. 
The information online regarding this has not been useful..
i have tried the below code:

```
 private void btnBookmark_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object missing = Type.Missing;
        try
        {

            string wordOutputPath="D:\\RC Docs\\Template\\WordDocumentName";

            objWordDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(wordOutputPath.ToString(), false, false, ref missing,
                                                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, true,
                                                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

            //how to retrieve the bookmarks from the document-code has to be written here

             objWordDoc.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need something like:

```
foreach (Bookmark bk in objWordDoc.Bookmarks) 
 { 
    string s = bk.Range.Text; 
    bk.Range.Text = s + "asd";
 }
```

Comment: i need to retrieve the data from bookmarks dynamically..there are about 150 bookmarks in the word document.

Comment: can't you use a foreach?  `foreach (Bookmark bk in objWordDoc.Bookmarks)
                { string s = bk.Range.Text; }`

Comment: yes im using for loop...inside the loop.im giving the below code..MessageBox.Show(objWordDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref objI).Name); but this is oly retrieving the name of the bookmark...i want the data which is in this bookmark..

Comment: mmm, are you sure that you actually have some text in your bookmark?

Comment: it's strange, the only possibility that I can though it's that the bookmarks are empty (0 chars), I need the file to test it.

Comment: Have you solved? If yes please set the question as "Answered" (if the answer satisfies your needs) and welcome to StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

Im able to retrieve the data from the bookmark of one document and insert it into a other document...but the format of the text is changing....
ex:
if i add some colour,font in the source document bookmark....the same format is not copied into the target documents bookmark...only the text is copied...